# Escaping Characters Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sanitization

I want to escape the inputs to this form so that when its enter in the database characters like .'* won't affect the update. How would I encode the characters to achieve the goal stated above.

```
<% form_for @post, :url => {:action => :createInnovation } do |form| %> 
  <fieldset>
    <p> Title: <br/><%= form.text_field :title, :html => {:class => "text ui-widget_content ui-corner-all" } %> </p>
    <p> Description: <br/> <%= form.text_area :body, :html => {:class => "text ui-widget_content ui-corner-all" } %> </p>
  </fieldset>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Can you post the code from your createInnovation action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveRecord will automatically escape any characters as needed to prevent sql injection.  Is that what you're concerned about?  If so, Rails has you covered.